# How to set a speed controller (Empty) for a particle emitter moving along a curve guide path?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm currently trying to make a particle system that will halt the movement of particles at a given timeframe with the help of an Empty controller. The particle has to move within a certain path guide. It is similar to the one in 3DSMax where you can add a Speed By Icon to control the particles along a path. How can this be achieved in Blender?

[Edit]: The timestep keyframe is the closest I can find but it doesn't work if the particle is partnered with a curve guide path.

[Edit]: I tried combining timestep and force field curve guide keyframes; I almost achieved my desired outcome, but when I had to resume the particle flow, the particles skipped like they were missing a frame. I want it to have a smooth stop-and-go animation flow.

Comment: can u pls add a link/animation how it should look like? thx